# Finding a Named column present in a table

Tags: sql

I am in spree to find a SQL or T-SQL query to get names of all the tables in a Database/Schema which have a column of given name.

Can any one help me in this please?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Should this question be tagged SQL Server only (as the answer varies dependent on database)

Comment: @JulesLt: `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` is at least somewhat standard. For example, here it is in MySql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html.

Comment: It's ANSI 92, but not supported on Larry's obvious exception!

Comment: I also want this job to be done in Oracle and DB2 too :)

Comment: DB2 should be fine - I think Oracle is the only major exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) system view:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'Name of column';
```

Comment: Works even for MSSQL 2000.

Answer (score 5):

This will find the columns you're after in the current/active database.  If you're in a different database, just prefix `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` with the database name (e.g. `dbname.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`)

```
DECLARE @Schema varchar(max)
DECLARE @Column varchar(max)

SET @Schema = NULL
SET @Column = 'primary_id'

SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME, *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @Column
    AND
    (
        @Schema IS NULL
            OR TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema
    )
```

This will work in SQL Server and should work in other DBMS's too since INFORMATION_SCHEMA is somewhat standardised (e.g. here it is in MySql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you all tables with a column named foo

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that while correct for SQL*Server (and mySQL - and postGres) the answer is different for Oracle, as they don't support the Information schema (which is ANSI SQL-92, so they have had plenty of time to do so).

On Oracle you would use

```
SELECT table_name, column_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE column_name = :column_name
```

Or you could create a schema and view to do the job of the missing information_schema.columns.

Comment: Found an open source project to add the missing support :
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ora-info-schema/

Answer (score 1):

`select TABLE_NAME from Your_Database_Name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME like '%ColumnName%' group by TABLE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

in sybase;

```
declare @column varchar(30)
select @column = 'column_name'
select object_name(id), @column from DB_NAME..syscolumns where name = @column
```